# Comparing lists with lists of lists

Tags: python, list

How can I check if a string of list2 is insinde a string of a list of list1?

For example:

```
list1 = [["CATTAC"], ["AGGA"]]
list2 = ["AT", "GG"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far (even if it maybe didn't work)?

Comment: i tried using multiple for-loops and tried of making use the any-function, but it didnt really work as expected (i'm a beginner so it wasnt rly surprising). Now i also tried with the answer below but i think i wasnt specific enough. I want sth that tells me, for example: Is GG (element of list2) inside AGGA (element of 2nd list of list2)? >>True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using loops

```
list1 = [["CATTAC"], ["AGGA"]]
list2 = ["AT", "GG"]
for x in range(len(list1)):
    for y in range(len(list2)):
        if str(list1[x]).find(str(list2[y])) == -1 :
            print("NO")
        else :
            print("YES")
```

Comment: This is working...but i don't rly understand the concept behind it. Could you explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: the loop(here by x) itirates the values of list 1. The sub loop(by y) checks each element of list 2 for every element in loop 1. The 5th line does is that it finds the yth element string of list 2 in xth string element of list 1 using the ".find" function. this find function returns -1 if it can not find the element. Thats it. If -1 is returned then the string is not found and otherwise it is found.

Answer (score 1):

Function returns true if element of list2 exists in list1

```
    def my_find(list1, list2):
        for cur in list2:
            for cur_list in list1:
                if cur in cur_list:
                    return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
list1 = [["CATTAC"], ["AGGA"]]
list2 = ["AT", "GG"]
res = [[l in e[0] for l in list2] for e in list1]
```